# Dynamic content for Android layout

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

Pardon the question title because I'm not really sure of the right term(s) to use.
I am just familiarizing myself with ListView and what I want to do is this:

-Suppose I have a Dog class which has *String name*, *String breed*, and *int age*.

-I would then make many instances of Dog and put them into a ListView which displays only their names.

-I would also have one layout, lets say *doginfo.xml*, that has the text "Name:", "Breed:", and "Age:".

So how can make the values of the clicked item (ie: name, breed, age) display on the next activity, which is *doginfo.xml*?

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you have an array/arraylist of your dogs and you are adding them in order to your listview. Check out the onItemClickListener of this exmaple in the android doc:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

In your click listener use "int position" to get the object from your array/arraylist. Once you have this information, you can pass it easily between activities using "bundle.putString()" and "b.getString()".

Look at this simple tutorial for information on passing data between activities:

http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Once you got your ListView, set an `OnItemClickListener`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Get your Dog object from the 'position' parameter you get here.
        //You should save the 'Dogs' in an array, so you can access them here easily.
        Dog d = mDogsArray[position];
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, DogInfoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", d.getName());
        intent.putExtra("breed", d.getBreed());
        intent.putExtra("age", d.getAge());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If you want to add/remove dogs dynamically, you can use the method `ListView.setListAdapter` to change the views the list view is showing. Create an array adapter this way:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dogs = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

and add dogs this way:

```
dogs.add(dogInfoString)
```

Comment: I have managed to get this working now, but is there a way to change the values of the object from the new activity?

Comment: You mean, change the value of the dog that was shown in the `DogInfoActivity` in the *actual* dogs array? It can be done, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Let me reply the step that you need to follow:

1. Create an arraylist of dog class object `ArrayList<DogClassObject>`
2. Now in 1st activity, just take the name from every object from ArrayList and add one by one name in `ArrayList<String>`.
3. Use the ArrayList to display inside the ListView of 1st activity.

To implement this, go through this example: [Android Simple ListView](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/android-listview-simple-listview-1/)

Now, to implement on click listener and to display dog_info, perform the below steps:

1. Implement OnItemClickListener inside the ListView.
2. Follow the answer given by @Jong but pass the clicked object from the ArrayList (you can get the clicked object from ArrayList by position argument).
3. Get the dog information and display name, age, breed info inside the dog_info
   To implement this, go through this example: [Android - Custom ListView with 2 TextViews](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-2-custom-listview/)

Comment: I have managed to get this working now, but is there a way to change the values of the object from the new activity?